# DLL функция поиска подстроки

Tags: c#, c++, массивы, dll

Есть оболчка в шарпе, которая передает, строку data и массив buffer, они передаются в функцию которая находится в dll. Эта функция должна искать нужные подстроки по опредленному тегу и записывать их в массив buffer. Я нахреначил какую-то ересь, в чем она работает так это в том, что она выдает мне 1ое вхождение в строке и все.

Сейчас же (в этом коде, buffer это как переменная, строка, но ее надо как-то грамотно сделать массивом...)

DLL:

```
h.
#define DLLEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DLLEXPORT void container(char* data, char* buffer);
```

cpp

```
DLLEXPORT void container(char* data, char* buffer){
string str1 = data;
int pos = 0;
string s2="(b c l a s s="needsclick")";
for(string::size_type i = 0; i < strlen(data); i++){
    if(str1.find(s2)){
        pos = str1.find(s2);
        cout<< pos;
        str1 = str1.substr(pos, 100);
        i += s2.length() - 1;
        break;
    }
}
cout<< str1;
strcpy(buffer, str1.c_str());
}
```

C#

Делегат:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate void ValuesSTR(string data, StringBuilder buffer);
```

Вызов:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(size);
ValuesSTR getNews = (ValuesSTR)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pProc, typeof(ValuesSTR));
getNews(data1, buffer);
```

Помогите написать функцию правильно.

Comment: Проблема в чем?

Comment: Что функция не совсем верно работала, сейчас использовал функцию unlimit'a, но не могу вернуть массив в C#

Comment: У вас написано "функция ищет нужные подстроки"

Comment: Да, верно, нужна была функция которая ищет нужные подстроки (эта функция в dll), но так же мне надо вернуть массив с этими строками в C#, в чем сейчас и состоит трудность..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непонятно почему не написать эту функцию на С#?
Почему искомую строку спрятали внутри функции?
Завтра искомая строка изменится и что теперь новую dll
создавать? 
И Вы уверены, что резать придется всегда 100 символов?

```
str1.substr(pos, 100);
```

И размер массива полученных подстрок тоже нужно будет вернуть из функции.
В общем вот так:

```
void container(const char* data,
                const char* findStr,
                int cutSize, 
                char  arrStr[][100],
                int * bufSize)

 {

std::string source (data);
std::vector<std::string> vecStr;

std::string::size_type pos = 0;
std::size_t cutLen = strlen(findStr) + cutSize;
while (std::string::npos !=
    (pos = source.find(findStr, pos)))
{
    vecStr.push_back(source.substr(pos, cutLen));
//  ++pos;
    pos += cutLen;
}

(*bufSize) = vecStr.size();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<std::size_t>(*bufSize); i++)
    strcpy(arrStr[i], vecStr[i].c_str());
```

}

Проверка:

```
const std::string str = "id1234 <string> but it stillid5678 keep making id9999the program crash..";
const std::string findStr = "id";
int  bufSize = 100;
char arr[100][100];


container(str.c_str(),findStr.c_str(),4, arr,&bufSize);

for (size_t i = 0; i < bufSize; i++)
{
    std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Результат:

id1234

id5678

id9999

Comment: Функция работает отлично! Спасибо Вам! Но вот теперь мучаюсь как ее вернуть в щарп! Буду разбираться!

Comment: По поводу почему нельзя в шарпе.. поверьте, была бы возможноть я бы сам так сделал :) Не моя прихоть..